# Convert fileoutputstream to a string

Tags: java

I have a java program where I am writing to a file using `OutputStream`. Everything is working fine. Upon completion of the program, I see data in my file. However, I would like to see this data on the `System.out` as well.

How can I convert `OutputStream` to a `String` so that I can simply `System.out.println();` it? I tried `fos.toString()` but that prints `java.io.FileOutputStream@1ed2e55e`

Comment: Just pass what ever data you pass to the `OutputStream` to write to the file to `System.out.println()`

Comment: Or after you are done writing to the file open a `FileInputStream` to read from the file what you have written to it - then use a `BufferedReader` to read it line by line and print it. This only makes sense if you want to see that your data was written correctly.

Comment: What inixsoftware said, or if the file isn't too big to read at once you could just print this out `new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file.txt")), "UTF-8")`.

Comment: I am writing to the fos like this in a loop: `fos.write((byte) mybyte)` however, when I do the same to `String s = (byte) mybyte` i get errors

Comment: Either do `System.out.print((char) mybyte);` or `sb.append((char) mybyte);`.

Comment: You could write your own `FilterOutputStream` that writes to `System.out` in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a ByteArrayOutputStream and you can create a string from it.  Assuming the 'stream' variable is a reference to your ByteArrayOutputStream in the following example, here's how you could do it...

```
System.out.println(new String(stream.toByteArray(), CharSet.defaultCharSet()));
```

EDIT: was missing a closing parenthesis above, fixed now

Comment: you forget `)` -> `System.out.println(new String(stream.toByteArray(), CharSet.defaultCharSet()))`;